# Does Azure AD support hierarchy of departments?

Tags: azure-active-directory

Does Azure AD support hierarchy of departments? Is it possible to create a department inside another department and then add users to both the departments?

Comment: Yes, But i think it's depends on your licenses check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/management-groups/overview

Comment: Thanks. Does this work in a multi-tenant setup?

Comment: By default, web app/API registrations in Azure AD are single-tenant. You can make your registration multi-tenant by finding the Supported account types switch on the Authentication pane of your application registration in the Azure portal and setting it to Accounts in any organizational directory.

Comment: This documentation it's good reference --> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/education/deploy/design-multi-tenant-architecture

Comment: Management group provides a level of scope above subscription groups. Seems like it is not applicable inside a subscription. The requirement is to support hierarchy of departments within a single subscription.